# read from file with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeof

Here's my text file -

```
15,13,12
10
10
```

and here's the .js file

```
var fs = require("fs");
var data = fs.readFileSync("someNumbers.txt", "utf8");

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    console.log(i + ": " + data[i] + ": " + typeof data[i]);
}
```

finally here's the output:

```
0: 1: string
1: 5: string
2: ,: string
3: 1: string
4: 3: string
5: ,: string
6: 1: string
7: 2: string
8: ,: string
: string
10:
: string
11: 1: string
12: 0: string
: string
14:
: string
15: 1: string
16: 0: string
```

I don't understand what is happening with the output after i gets to 9;
I will be grateful for an explanation.
Gerard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running into issues when you try include a carriage return and/or linefeed from the original file in a string and then send that string to `console.log()`.   Change your code to put the hex value instead of the actual value and your issue should clear up:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var data = fs.readFileSync("someNumbers.txt", "utf8");

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    console.log(i + ": " + data.charCodeAt(i).toString(16). + ": " + typeof data[i]);
}
```

Or, just skip any non-printable characters:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var data = fs.readFileSync("someNumbers.txt", "utf8");

for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    var ch = data.charCodeAt(i);
    if (ch > 32 && ch <= 127) {
        console.log(i + ": " + ch + ": " + typeof ch);
    }
}
```

Note, when you read the file and told it to interpret it as utf8, you're already making it so that `typeof` every item in that data is going to be treated as a string whether it really is or isn't.  You've already told Javascript to make it all a string.

Answer (score 1):

It reads end of line (new line) character, which cannot be displayed.  This character messes up with corresponding lines of output of `console.log`.